# Eror in flutter "Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'"

Tags: flutter

This my code

```dart
class ProdukAPI {
  Future<List<listProduk>> getProduk() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.2.17:3000/produk/tampil'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse.map((data) => listProduk.fromJson(data)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me please

Comment: This error can be troubleshooted in a more detail the JSON output. Whatdid you get of your http.get request?

Comment: just data from api